# pandas raising OutOfBoundsDatetime on csv but not on sql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

I have one service running pandas version 0.25.2. This service reads data from a database and stores a snapshot as csv

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_cmd, oracle)
```

the query result in a dataframe with some very large datetime values. (e.g. 3000-01-02 00:00:00)
Afterwards I use `df.to_csv(index=False)` to create a csv snapshot and write it into a file

on a diffrent machine with pandas 0.25.3 installed, i am reading the content of the csv file into a dataframe and try to change the datatype of the date column to datetime. This results in a `OutOfBoundsDatetime` Exception

```
df = pd.read_csv("xy.csv")
pd.to_datetime(df['val_until'])

pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3000-01-02 00:00:00
```

I am thinking about using pickle to create the snapshots an load the dataframes directly. However, I am curious why pandas is able to handle a big datetime in the first case and not in the second one.
Also any suggestions how I keep using csv as transfer format are appreciated

Comment: Do you initialize your df with any particular data type? If you didn't when you read the data in, it could be one assumed data type and another in the 2nd case. This could be two data types with different max/min values, which is resulting in an acceptable value for one case, but overflow in the next.

Comment: Reading it again, your first df likely contains strings if you are not manually setting any data type during some initializer line (not shown here). You are then trying to convert this perfectly acceptable length string, to an actual datetime data type, which has a maximum value of this data type. Looking at the python docs on the datetime datatype it looks like the [MAXYEAR](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.MAXYEAR) is 9999, so not sure why 3000 would be a problem.

Comment: yes you are right. after checking the dtypes of the sqlquery I can confirm that the type of the 'val_until' column is `object`. So it already did not parse the date on the first cmd. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I got it.

In the first case, I'm not sure what the actual data type is that is stored in the sql database, but if not otherwise specified, reading it into the df likely results in some generic or string type which has a much higher overflow value.

Eventually though, it ends up in a csv file which is a string type. This can be incredibly (infinitely?) long without any overflow, whereas the data type you are trying to cast into using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime) docs. has a maximum value of [_'2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html?highlight=timestamp%20max#pandas.Timestamp.max) according to the Timestamp.max shown in the first doc link at the bottom.

Comment: correct. the 'val_until' on the sql query is a type object

Comment: Yep, thats just a generic parent type. I guess you can use the `parse_dates` parameter in the [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html?highlight=read_sql_query#pandas.read_sql_query) call, or initialize your df in an earlier line specifying which data types you want it to hold.